# Transparency on only one side

Tags: aframe

I was trying to add some transparency to a text and oddly enough I noticed it was only transparent on one side while being opaque on the other.

The expected behavior was transparent on both sides. Any idea why this happens?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/material.html#transparency-issues

With opacity, A-Frame sets three.js renderer to `sortObjects: false`. Transparency ordering is based on when objects are added / defined in the scene. Shuffle the order of the text in like the HTML or when they are injected and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Kevin.